# MAMP Apache Won't Start after OS X 10.8 (Mountain Lion) update

Tags: macos, apache, localhost, mamp, osx-mountain-lion

Today I updated to OS X Mountain Lion. I noticed that Apache won't start in MAMP. Nothing new seems to be in the apache log file. Running `sudo apachectl -k start` in Terminal gives me this:

```
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using Ryan-Smiths-MacBook.local for ServerName
```

I do have ServerName defined in my `httpd.conf` file.

I also noticed that "Web sharing" is no longer in the Settings pane... weird.

Any Ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: OS X Mountain Lion still includes Apache, but the "Web Sharing" preference is Gone! (ref Apple Support: [OS X Mountain Lion: Options for web sharing](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5230?viewlocale=en_US)).  If you are running PHP apps it would be worth looking into [MAMP](http://mamp.info/en/mamp/index.html) as a better replacement (it includes MySQL, phpMyAdmin, and some related programs & libraries).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Hi Ryan we had this problem

It turns out the systems own apache is running. We've documented it here http://support.servertastic.com/mamp-not-starting-after-upgrade-to-mountain-lion/

Cheers

Richard

Answer (score 10):

To fix the problem, and to start MAMP apache, you can now refer to: (the above link is broken now.)

https://support.servertastic.com/mamp-not-starting-after-upgrade-to-mountain-lion/

Or simply run the following command:

```
sudo apachectl stop
```

In addition if you run into trouble where your mysql no longer will start, try killing the mysql process that may already be running by doing the following:

1. Open up the program called "Activity Monitor" on your Mac.
2. Search for a process called “mysqld“.
3. Click on that process and “Quit Process”

Credits:
http://eliteeternity.com/mysql-server-wont-start-mamp-red-light-mac/
http://forum.mamp.info/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=6149

Comment: The above sude command for stopping the default apache server worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In MAMP PRO 2.1.1, click **Tools** > **Quit Built-in Apache**.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this running OS X 10.8.4 by opening up Activity Monitor, choosing "All Processes" then killing any with "httpd" in the title. After that I was able to start MAMP and both the MYSQL and Apache servers gave the green light!

Answer (score 2):

this one fix my MAMP

> Just navigate to /Applications/MAMP/bin/apache2/bin using Finder, and rename envvars to _envvars (yes, just add the underscore). Boom! Done and done.

from [codesoap](http://codesoap.com/mamp-pro-apache-and/)

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem; no other tricks helped. I found I had an instance with "allow from 127.0.0.1" – removing the IP did the trick. Don't know why.

http://cl.ly/image/253g1L1W472z

Answer (score 1):

The problem with OSX Mountain Lion is that `/usr/lib/libpq.5.3.dylib` does not exist, but `/usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib` does.

To fix the issue, open terminal and:

```
~# sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libpq.5.3.dylib /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib
```

Comment: Am I right that you want to turn that around?  So the command is `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib /usr/lib/libpq.5.3.dylib` ...?

Answer (score 1):

just try to modify mamp in httpd.conf with:

> LoadModule php5_module /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/modules/libphp5.so

Answer (score 1):

My solution to the similar problem. I.e. MySQL was running fine from MAMP manager utility. Apache server did not and the "Open start page" was greyed i.e. not working.

It seems that my problem was, that the Apache server was not for one reason or another able to access it's log file apache_error.log in /Applications/MAMP/logs folder. The file seemed to be somehow "stuck" i.e. I was not able to change the access rights to the file with chmod command. Only after I deleted the log file completely and then restarted the MAMP control utility and started there the MySQL and Apache again, everything worked fine.

BR,
Janne

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem.

I then set the `ServerName` to `localhost` and the `Listen` port to `8080`, because 80 was somehow not available (even not as sudo). In my case it seems to have fixed the problem.

Comment: Port 80 isn't available because the in-built Apache is running on that port, stop it as covered in my answer and you should be able to use it again

Answer (score 0):

If nothing works for you like me, the problem is likely that you ran your MAMP update with MAMP running, then you closed the existing MAMP without stopping your server. All you need to do is restart your machine.